# How to cusstomize list item of TweetTimelineListAdapter for android?

Tags: android, twitter

I am following example to create listfragment http://docs.fabric.io/android/twitter/show-timelines.html

```
public class TwitterFeedFragment extends ListFragment{

    UserTimeline searchTimeline;
    TweetTimelineListAdapter adapter;
    SwipeRefreshLayout swipeLayout;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        searchTimeline = new UserTimeline.Builder().includeReplies(false)
            .screenName("verabrezhneva")
            .includeRetweets(false)

            .build();
        adapter = new TweetTimelineListAdapter(
            getActivity(), searchTimeline
        );
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(
        LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState
    ){
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_feed_twitter, container, false);
        swipeLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.swipe_refresh_layout);
        swipeLayout.setOnRefreshListener(
            new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener(){

                @Override
                public void onRefresh(){
                    swipeLayout.setRefreshing(true);
                    adapter.refresh(
                        new Callback<TimelineResult<Tweet>>(){

                            @Override
                            public void success(Result<TimelineResult<Tweet>> result){
                                swipeLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                            }


                            @Override
                            public void failure(TwitterException exception){
                                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Cannot update timeline",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                    );
                }
            }
        );
        return v;
    }
}
```

and i can get nice tweet timeline
[image]
However default style does not much my app style. How can I customize listitems?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Provide custom styling as per your requirement. More @ http://docs.fabric.io/android/twitter/show-tweets.html#styling

Answer (score 0):

Dont know whe someone devoted @Nag. However there is more detailed solution.
First of all there is an [responce from developer](https://github.com/twitter/twitter-kit-android/issues/22#issuecomment-127684934)

> In tweet-ui 1.3.1 and before, you'll have to override the adapter's
>   getView to apply a custom style to the view. In the sample you might
>   use the following to set the dark style on each CompactTweetView.
>
> ```
> final TweetTimelineListAdapter adapter = new TweetTimelineListAdapter(this, timeline) {
>             @Override
>             public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
>                 View rowView = convertView;
>                 final Tweet tweet = getItem(position);
>                 if (rowView == null) {
>                     rowView = new CompactTweetView(context, tweet, R.style.tw__TweetDarkStyle);
>                 } else {
>                     ((BaseTweetView) rowView).setTweet(tweet);
>                 }
>                 return rowView;
>             }
>         };
> ```
>
> See the styling docs to see how to extend the provided
>   tw__TweetLightStyle and tw__TweetDarkStyle styles.
>
> In the next releases for tweet-ui 1.4.+, TweetTimelineListAdapter will
>   provide a Builder with a setViewStyle(int styleResId) setter to
>   simplify view customization.

Then you can replace standart style with you own

```
<style name="CustomLightTweetStyle" parent="tw__TweetDarkStyle">
        <item name="tw__primary_text_color">@color/white</item>
        <item name="tw__action_color">@color/white_text_60</item>
        <item name="tw__container_bg_color">@color/dark_gray</item>
</style>
```

If you want to change elements order you can extend `CompactTweetView` and override `getLayout` to return your tweet layout (dont forget to adapt ather variable if nessessary . There is a [source](https://github.com/twitter/twitter-kit-android/blob/master/tweet-ui/src/main/java/com/twitter/sdk/android/tweetui/CompactTweetView.java)

```
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Build;
import android.util.AttributeSet;

import com.twitter.sdk.android.core.models.MediaEntity;
import com.twitter.sdk.android.core.models.Tweet;

public class CompactTweetView extends BaseTweetView {
    private static final String VIEW_TYPE_NAME = "compact";
    private static final double SQUARE_ASPECT_RATIO = 1.0;
    private static final double MAX_LANDSCAPE_ASPECT_RATIO = 3.0;
    private static final double MIN_LANDSCAPE_ASPECT_RATIO = 4.0 / 3.0;

    public CompactTweetView(Context context, Tweet tweet) {
        super(context, tweet);
    }

    public CompactTweetView(Context context, Tweet tweet, int styleResId) {
        super(context, tweet, styleResId);
    }

    CompactTweetView(Context context, Tweet tweet, int styleResId,
            DependencyProvider dependencyProvider) {
        super(context, tweet, styleResId, dependencyProvider);
    }

    public CompactTweetView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    public CompactTweetView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    protected int getLayout() {
        return R.layout.tw__tweet_compact;
    }

    @Override
    void render() {
        super.render();
        // Redraw screen name on recycle
        screenNameView.requestLayout();
    }

    /**
     * Returns the desired aspect ratio of the Tweet media entity according to "sizes" metadata
     * and the aspect ratio display rules.
     * @param photoEntity the first
     * @return the target image and bitmap width to height aspect ratio
     */
    @Override
    protected double getAspectRatio(MediaEntity photoEntity) {
        final double ratio = super.getAspectRatio(photoEntity);
        if (ratio <= SQUARE_ASPECT_RATIO) {
            // portrait (tall) photos should be cropped to be square aspect ratio
            return SQUARE_ASPECT_RATIO;
        } else if (ratio > MAX_LANDSCAPE_ASPECT_RATIO) {
            // the widest landscape photos allowed are 3:1
            return MAX_LANDSCAPE_ASPECT_RATIO;
        } else if (ratio < MIN_LANDSCAPE_ASPECT_RATIO) {
            // the tallest landscape photos allowed are 4:3
            return MIN_LANDSCAPE_ASPECT_RATIO;
        } else {
            // landscape photos between 3:1 to 4:3 present the original width to height ratio
            return ratio;
        }
    }

    @Override
    String getViewTypeName() {
        return VIEW_TYPE_NAME;
    }
}
```

and [original layout](https://github.com/twitter/twitter-kit-android/blob/master/tweet-ui/src/main/res/layout/tw__tweet_compact.xml)

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/tw__tweet_view"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    style="@style/tw__CompactTweetContainer">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tw__tweet_retweeted_by"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tw__author_attribution"
        style="@style/tw__TweetRetweetedBy.Compact"
        tools:text="retweeted by"/>

    <ImageView
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription"
        android:id="@+id/tw__tweet_author_avatar"
        android:layout_below="@id/tw__tweet_retweeted_by"
        style="@style/tw__TweetAvatar.Compact"
        tools:background="@color/tw__tweet_media_preview_bg_color"/>

    <!--Name and timestamp don't ellipsize, but @username in the middle does ellipsize-->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/tw__author_attribution"
        style="@style/tw__CompactAttributionLine"
        android:layout_below="@id/tw__tweet_retweeted_by"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/tw__tweet_author_avatar"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/tw__tweet_author_avatar">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tw__tweet_author_full_name"
            style="@style/tw__TweetFullName.Compact"
            tools:text="Jack"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tw__tweet_author_screen_name"
            style="@style/tw__TweetScreenName.Compact"
            tools:text="\@jack"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tw__tweet_timestamp"
            style="@style/tw__TweetTimestamp.Compact"
            tools:text="• 03/21/2006"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription"
        android:id="@+id/tw__twitter_logo"
        style="@style/tw__TwitterLogo.Compact"
        android:layout_below="@id/tw__tweet_retweeted_by"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>

    <com.twitter.sdk.android.tweetui.internal.util.AspectRatioImageView
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription"
        android:id="@+id/tw__tweet_media"
        style="@style/tw__TweetMedia.Compact"
        android:layout_below="@id/tw__author_attribution"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/tw__tweet_author_avatar"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/tw__tweet_author_avatar"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tw__tweet_text"
        style="@style/tw__TweetText.Compact"
        android:layout_below="@id/tw__tweet_media"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/tw__tweet_author_avatar"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/tw__tweet_author_avatar"
        tools:text="just setting up my twttr"/>

    <include
        style="@style/tw__TweetActionButtonBar.Compact"
        layout="@layout/tw__action_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/tw__tweet_text"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/tw__tweet_author_avatar"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/tw__tweet_author_avatar"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```